# Join on two tables with exact number of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 
Tracks and Tags

Table Track (T1)

```
id Name
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Table Tags (T2)

```
id track_id name
1  1        a1
2  1        b1
3  1        c2
4  1        d2
5  2        a3
6  2        b3
7  2        c2
8  2        d2
9  3        a1
10 3        b1
11 3        c3
12 3        d3
13 4        a1
14 4        b2
15 4        c3
16 4        d1
```

I want to select list of tracks that have a1 and b1 exactly and one or both of these tags c2, c3.
The query should return track 1 and 3

Comment: Pls, provide desired output also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want the track_id, there is no need for table T1.

```
 select    track_id

 from      t2

 where     name in ('a1','b1','c2','c3')

 group by  track_id

 having    count(case when name = 'a1' then 1 end) = 1 
       and count(case when name = 'b1' then 1 end) = 1  
       and count(case when name in ('c2','c3') then 1 end) > 0
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by tracks and take only those having the conditions you mentioned in the group

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.track_id
group by t1.id, t1.name
having sum(t2.name = 'a1') > 0
   and sum(t2.name = 'b1') > 0
   and sum(t2.name in ('c2','c3')) > 0
```

Comment: The request was for track_id, so no need for T1.

Comment: @MohamedBenSalah: In your question there is a table with such a column name.